# Exportar dados da consulta SQL para o Excel

Tags: sql, microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-access, relatório

Boa tarde pessoal.

Criei um banco de dados para controle de recebimento e entrega de cartões. A inclusão dos dados é realizada através de um formulário no excel.

Esse formulário também tem a opção de consulta dos dados já existentes. a consulta devolve as informações no próprio formulário para visualização em tela.

O meu problema é que caso exista mais de um registro não será possível verificar todos eles no formulário. A minha saída então foi criar uma espécie de relatório. Ao clicar em consultar primeiro é chamada uma função que conta quantos registros a consulta retornará. Se for mais de um é criado um arquivo excel onde os registros seriam guardados. Entretanto a função Insert Into OpenRowSet está apresentando erro.

Disponibilizo abaixo os códigos. Se alguém puder me dar um luz eu agradeço.

Esse código é o contador. ele verifica no BD quantos registros são compatíveis com o critério de busca.

```
    Public Function Contador()

        Dim TOTAL As Variant

        Dim sql As String
        Dim cn  As ADODB.Connection
        Dim rs  As ADODB.Recordset

        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

        cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & enderecoDB & ";Jet OLEDB:Database"

        cn.Open

        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

        sql = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM controle WHERE BP = '" & controlectform.nmbpbox.Value & "';"

        rs.Open sql, cn

        If Not rs.EOF Then
            Do While Not rs.EOF
                TOTAL = rs(0)
                rs.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If

        cn.Close

        Contador = TOTAL
End Function
```

Se o valor retornado for maior que 1 (Contador>1) então é chamada uma função que cria o arquivo xls:

```
Public Function CriaArquivo()

    Dim NovoArquivoXLS      As Workbook
    Dim sht                 As Worksheet
    Dim mPathSave           As String
    Dim PlanName            As String


    mPathSave = ThisWorkbook.Path

    PlanName = "SQLQueryControleCartoes"

    'Cria um novo arquivo excel
    Set NovoArquivoXLS = Application.Workbooks.Add

    'Salva o arquivo
    NovoArquivoXLS.SaveAs mPathSave & "\" & PlanName & ".xls"

    Call Cabecalho

End Function
```

A função CriarArquivo, por sua vez, chama uma outra função que insere o cabeçalho:

```
Public Function Cabecalho()

    Dim vArray As Variant 'variável insere dados vArray
    Dim vContador As Integer

    ' variavel vArrays variant com array de dados
    vArray = Array("", "ID", "TP_BENEFICIO", "BP", "CPF", "NOME", "DTADM", "FILIAL", "SOLICPOR", "DTSOLIC", _
    "DTRECEBE", "DTENVIOBS", "ENVIADORETIRADO", "NMMINUTA", "NRCARTAO")

    'Inserindo o cabeçalho na folha de planilha

    With Worksheets("Planilha1")
    For vContador = 1 To UBound(vArray)
    .Cells(1, vContador).Value = vArray(vContador)
    Next vContador
    End With

End Function
```

Após todo esse processo é chamada a função para inserir os dados na planilha:

```
Public Function Relatorio()

    Dim sql As String
    Dim cn  As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs  As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rel As String


    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & enderecoDB & ";Jet OLEDB:Database"

    cn.Open

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    sql = "INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database= " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\SQLQueryControleCartoes.xls', 'SELECT * FROM controle WHERE BP = '" & controlectform.nmbpbox.Value & "')"

    rs.Open sql, cn

End Function
```

Todos os códigos são executados normalmente. O arquivo é criado e o cabeçalho inserido. Mas na hora de inserir os resultados da consulta é apresentado o erro abaixo:

[image: erro instrução Insert Into OpenRowSet]

O erro é apontado na penúltima linha da função relatório onde consta o "rs.Open sql,cn"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753278/insert-into-openrowset-syntax-with-dynamic-t-sql

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo obrigado pelo link. Tentei fazer como mostrado lá porém continua apresentando erro.  Set sql = 'INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 12.0;Database='U:\CSU\TAM\Controle Cartões\database\SQLQueryControleCartoes.xls''',''SELECT * FROM [Planilha1$]'') SELECT * FROM controle WHERE BP = '''controlectform.nmbpbox.Value''''  Aparece uma mensagem dizendo "Erro de Compilação! Era esperado: Expressão"

Comment: Eu diria que essas aspas não estão balanceadas.

Comment: Olhei as aspas, escrevi o código e comparei com o código disponível no link acima. Mesmo assim apresentou erro.  Procurei mais um pouco e desenvolvi o código assim:                                                                                   sql = "INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=U:\CSU\TAM\Controle\SQLQueryControleCartoes.xls;', 'SELECT * FROM [Planilha1$]') SELECT * FROM controle WHERE BP = " & controlectform.nmbpbox.Value & ";"   Mesmo assim continua com erro. Agora diz que não foi possível localizar a tabela de saída OPENROWSET.

Comment: Veja esse outro link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909933/sql-server-export-to-excel-with-openrowset

Comment: Reginaldo,  Agradeço pela ajuda, entretanto continua apresentando erro. O código disponível no lik acima apresenta a mesma mensagem do primeiro "Erro de Compilação! Era esperado: Expressão", revi toda a estrutura e rescrevi o código, mesmo assim o erro persiste.Tentei usar também o método DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet porém também dá erro. Diz que o método "TransferirPlanilha" não está disponível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema.

Deixo abaixo o código, caso mais alguém precise:

```
Public Function Relatorio()

    Dim sql As String
    Dim cn  As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs  As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rel As String


    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & enderecoDB & ";Jet OLEDB:Database"

    cn.Open

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim path_To_XLSX
    Dim name_of_sheet
    path_To_XLSX = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CustomReports  " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & Format(Time, "  hh.mm.ss") & ".xls"
    name_of_sheet = "Planilha1"
    sql = "SELECT * INTO [Excel 12.0;Database=" & path_To_XLSX & "]." & name_of_sheet & " FROM controle WHERE BP = '" & controlectform.nmbpbox.Value & "';"

    rs.Open sql, cn

End Function
```

Com esse código não precisei mais da função que cria o arquivo.