# Utilização de TransferSpreadSheet via VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-access

Estou finalizando meu projeto de melhoria e tem algo que me intriga bastante.

Precisei fazer um relatório com base no resultado de uma consulta SQL, que eu até questionei em [Exportar dados da consulta SQL para o Excel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193939/exportar-dados-da-consulta-sql-para-o-excel/195587#195587), e agora eu preciso fazer o contrário e importar dados de uma planilha em excel para o access.

Como não tenho muito conhecimento sobre o VBA, muitas coisas que já fiz eu precisei pesquisar muito antes. Em todos os casos sempre apareceu como opção usar o método DoCmd.TransferSpreadSheet. Entretanto todas as vezes que tentei utilizá-lo o excel retornou uma mensagem de erro dizendo:

> O comando ou ação "TransferirPlanilha" não está disponível agora.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Posso usar esse comando dentro do excel? Ou ele deve ser usado só no Access?

No meu caso eu tenho o DB criado com o Access, e um formulário criado no excel para realizar o cadastro das informações no DB.

Nesse formulário eu tenho um botão "Atualizar Base", quando o usuário clicar no botão ele deveria, em tese, copiar os dados de uma determinada planilha para dentro de uma tabela do BD.

Pelas minhas pesquisas o código não seria muito complexo, ficaria algo parecido com isso:

```
Private Sub atualizarbase_btn_Click()
    Dim strXls As String

    strXls = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ATIVOS\ativos.xlsx"

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "ativos", strXls, True, "ativos!"

End Sub
```

Como posso fazer isso funcionar?

Comment: O objeto `DoCmd` é exclusivo do Access.

Comment: Não é uma coisa difícil de se resolver, mas tenho algumas dúvidas em relação ao que você está querendo fazer. **1** - Essa planilha fica sempre no mesmo local? **2** - Não poderia incluir os dados diretamente no Access ao invés da planilha e depois para o Access?

Comment: Pergunto isso pq no caso **1** vc poderia simplesmente criar uma tabela vinculada dentro do Access e no caso **2** vc poderia fazer com que a aba `ativos` sempre recebesse os dados da tabela `ativos` através de uma conexão.

Comment: @Marco sim a planilha sempre ficará no mesmo local. Mas ela pode ser substituída mensalmente. Essa planilha de ativos contém todos os colaboradores da empresa. Então todo mês sera gerada uma nova planilha com os dados. Essa planilha será salva no mesmo local e com o mesmo nome (sobrescrevendo a anterior) e os novos colaboradores devem ser importados para a tabela do Access. Como eu já tenho um formulário que se conecta com o BD seria interessante apenas adicionar um botão nele para fazer a importação.

Comment: Como esse formulário será usado por outras pessoas, que não tem tanto conhecimento sobre BD, programação e etc, eu preferia que elas não precisassem usar o Access para importar pois evitaria problemas.

Comment: É que da maneira como foi colocado, me parece que você quer que a tabela no BD seja sempre substituída pelos dados da planilha que está sendo usada no momento.

Comment: Fazer essa inclusão através da planilha irá atrapalhar por exemplo na consistência, por exemplo, de não precisar atualizar ou inserir algo que já está no BD.

Comment: E em relação ao conhecimento sobre BD e programação, isso é irrelevante pois você consegue deixar o arquivo Access com cara de um sistema para que seja feita essa inclusão por uma interface amigável.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como eu disse nos comentários da sua pergunta, existem outras maneiras de se fazer o que você pretende, porém respondendo diretamente a pergunta de como utilizar o `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` no VBA dentro do Excel, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
Sub TransferirPlanilha()
    Dim strCaminhoDB as String, strXls as String
    Dim appAccess as Access.Application

    strCaminhoDB = "C:\Ativos.accdb"
    strXls = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ATIVOS\ativos.xlsx"

    Set appAccess = New Access.Application

    With appAccess
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .OpenCurrentDatabase strCaminhoDB
        .DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "ativos", strXls, True, "ativos!"
        .Quit
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    Set appAccess = Nothing
End Sub
```

Sem esquecer das referências para executar o código acima:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: sei que poderia utilizar no próprio access, porém já tenho um formulário que se conecta ao BD. Achei que seria mais fácil, tanto pra mim quanto para o usuário final, se todas as opções ficassem disponíveis num local só. Dessa forma economizaria tempo de buscar informações em outros locais.  Seu código atendeu perfeitamente o que eu precisava fazer. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu, apenas tenha cuidado pois você estará sempre sobrepondo os dados. Mas se atendeu a sua demanda, creio que você saiba dos riscos. Abraço